# complie and link,warning not found libpcre.so.1

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, g++

When I complie the program with CUDA and OPenCV, it is fine just complie(using -c), but warning occurs while it links:

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -m64 -I /usr/local/include -I /usr/local/include/opencv -I /usr/local/include/opencv2  -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -o rgb  smooth_tex.cu 
5 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -m64 -I /usr/local/include -I /usr/local/include/opencv -I /usr/local/include/opencv2 -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -o rgb smooth_tex.cu
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpcre.so.1, needed by //home/dzqiu/anaconda2/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

I am confused that why it will link the library in anaconda2 ? And I checked the libgobject-2.0.so.0,and found it was likely OK:

[image]

but when I run `rpm -ql pcre`, it shows :

```
package pcre is not installed
```

I try to install the libpcre3, but it shows that libpcre3 is already the newest version (2:8.38-3.1),but not in the /lib64,/lib/,usr/local/lib/, I try to link the libpcre.so.1 from anaconda2, but it doesn't work.

I also add the -L to link the OpenCV's library(/usr/local/lib/) or the anaconda2's library, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions to fix?

Comment: Not sure if this will solve it, but generally you need the dev part of the library to compile... libpcre3-dev for example... I do not recall this library being needed by OpenCV though (maybe I am wrong)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have already installed the libpcre3-dev, libpcre3, but the warning occurred also.

Comment: Now I meet a  similar problem, I just add the lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it works. I think adding the anaconda's lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH can slove, but  I have installed a system again so the problem disappeared.
If somebody meets this kind of warning, try to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<your anaconda>/lib"

Comment: added as an answer, this way other people may find easily the solution to this problem

Answer (score 7):

I meet a  similar problem, try to add anaconda's lib to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<your anaconda>/lib"
```

maybe it can fix it.